# Started from the wrong branch, how do I get my changes into the correct one in a pull request?

Tags: git, github

Made a nice move a couple of days ago.  We use git flow here and I'm supposed to branch from our develop branch to do some work.

Instead, I branched from master by mistake, made my changes, committed, and pushed to my branch on github.  Now, when I look to open a pull request to the develop branch on github it's got a bunch of changes from the master branch mixed in.

Looking for a good way to fix this, or start over if need be, and merge my changes into the develop branch without master being involved?

Comment: It really depends on how different master and develop are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create a new branch from "develop" branch and cherrypick your changes that you did on master to this branch. Then reset the master branch to wherever the last clean state. Now push your new branch. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/) ("git rebase -i develop", then remove commits from master) or (if there are a lot of commits from master) just cherry-pick your commits to the new branch - then force push and inform everybody who is working with your branch because of future conflicts (this process changes history of the branch). (And I recommend making backup branch if this is your first rebase, just for sure. :])